# Integrate maizzle project with responsively app by manojVivek using javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a maizzle project running and the other is responsively running on two different ports - I have to send a request with an HTML file from maizzle to responsively and get the respective device screenshot from it using javascript. How do I integrate it?

Answer (score 0):

You can run `maizzle serve` to spin up a development server with Browsersync in Maizzle, and then visit that URL in the Responsively app and take the screenshots.